# Reduce call gives odd errors from REPL and compiler

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

This is an example in a book:

```
(reduce (lambda (best itemx)
          (if (and (evenp itemx) (> itemx best)) 
              itemx
              best))
        '(1 2 3 4 5 6)
        :initial-value 0)
```

It shows as running fine in the book but in my SBCL REPL I get an error "undefinied variabled" and it gives the name of that variable as a blank (or maybe a few spaces).

Does anything stand out as odd here?

I also tried turning it into a function:

```
(defun find-largest-even (list) 
  (reduce (lambda (best itemx)
            (if (and (evenp itemx) (> itemx best)) 
                itemx
                best))
          list
          :initial-value 0))
```

However this doesn't compile. It highlights `itemx` in the lambda arguments and reports: `the octet sequence #(244) cannot be decoded.`

Comment: I advise you not to just give us code and ask what is wrong. it isn't a massive code dump, but nevertheless it is still just asking what is wrong.

Comment: @someone-or-other that is exactly the kind of question this site is for man.

Comment: I don't see a problem here. @someone-or-other SO is full of code blocks where folks legitimately try to debug and find errors. So of course they are asking what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as you pasted is fine.

The behavior you describe is indicative of lisp choking on a non-ascii character.

Please copy the code into Emacs and find the offending character using, e.g.,

```
(defun my-search-for-non-acsii ()
  (interactive)
  (skip-chars-forward "\000-\177"))
```

Comment: thanks, that was helpful to know how those errors translate into the problem